# Programmatically generated x509 identities will not import using SecPKCS12Import function

Tags: xcode, macos, openssl, x509

I am trying to add programmatically generated identities to an OSX keychain using the function `SecPKCS12Import`.

Everything is fine for certs that are generated using the KeychainAssistant program. Programmatically generating a practically identical certificate will not import even though `SecPKCSImport` reports no errors. Here are the two certificates. First is the one that imports:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=Tes001, C=US
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 14 21:05:31 2015 GMT
            Not After : Mar 13 21:05:31 2016 GMT
        Subject: CN=Tes001, C=US
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    00:c0:fc:0b:81:1f:b7:9f:d2:bb:eb:50:6d:0d:9a:
                    35:3b:b3:a6:26:e5:b1:67:99:0f:51:30:2b:f5:a4:
                    ...
                    a7:76:60:ab:72:3f:21:48:aa:37:ca:b4:6e:b1:b0:
                    06:85
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
                E-mail Protection
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        3d:d8:72:a8:85:f7:4d:6e:52:08:16:cc:76:40:33:9e:41:0d:
        48:f0:ba:0c:b2:03:d5:06:9a:bb:95:54:48:1d:db:6f:fe:97:
        ...
        ac:37:a3:ee:11:65:3b:e7:8f:26:f0:09:ae:ed:e0:53:e4:34:
        40:1c:ef:bd
No Trusted Uses.
No Rejected Uses.
Alias: Tes001
Key Id: 3A:2F:24:91:A9:D7:FA:C2:C5:48:56:86:11:89:E4:41:A0:24:07:F8
```

and here is the one that will not load:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, CN=Test001
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 14 23:46:07 2015 GMT
            Not After : Mar 13 23:46:07 2016 GMT
        Subject: C=US, CN=Test001
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    00:be:86:09:de:8e:08:4d:4a:14:b4:e9:7b:b2:bb:
                    c6:87:09:3b:c1:5f:9e:0e:bc:58:93:44:7d:b1:7b:
                    ...
                    38:b0:84:0c:08:22:fd:96:a8:0a:09:90:a7:e8:35:
                    11:c9
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        8e:d1:e5:b3:55:ee:04:dd:bc:15:32:1d:6b:3b:a9:e1:6f:c7:
        0b:5e:6d:51:a5:d0:82:52:f5:6d:f5:89:97:71:2a:26:fc:f1:
        ...
        aa:37:fe:fc:80:34:8e:2a:ec:6d:c9:7e:25:b2:c1:f5:65:2f:
        25:4a:ad:b8
```

The only significant difference is the last four lines of the first certificate:

```
No Trusted Uses.
No Rejected Uses.
Alias: Tes001
Key Id: 3A:2F:24:91:A9:D7:FA:C2:C5:48:56:86:11:89:E4:41:A0:24:07:F8
```

I don't know how to produce this programmatically.  I know that the function
`X509_alias_set1(self.x509, "Test001", -1)` will generate the first three lines, though I'm not sure it's correct. I don't know how to generate the "Key Id:" line.  I think it has something to do with the Trust Commands for a Trusted Certificate as per the openssl command. Any thoughts?

Comment: A PKCS12 require a private key and cert pair. The first one looks to have the key whereas the second does not.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's significant to what you're trying to do but you seem to have a typo in the alias for the first key pair - tes001 (note the lack of a second "t")

Comment: `No Trusted Uses` and friends sounds like is coming from Keychain or its API. Its not part of the certificate data. You should show the code you are using to save the cert. You should also show the *full certificate* as dumped by `openssl x509 -in <cert> -inform DER -text -noout`. Finally, what kind of end-entity certificate is this? Is it a user or server certificate (Its not apparent from the Subject DN)? From the first certificate, it looks like its a user cert because of S/MIME (E-mail Protection).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  It spurred me on to get to the bottom of this, as I explain in the follow-on posting. I was in a learning mode, so the certificates were somewhat artificial, and hence some of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

1.) The code worked fine. The problem was that the cert and the private key were directly imported into the keychain. Having the same cert already present in the keychain would cause the new one to not be imported nor would it be returned in the items dictionary of the SecPKCS12Import function. No error was reported (because the PKCS12 was correct) and no data was returned. This was not clear at all, particularly given the official description of SecPKCS12Import: "You can then use the Keychain Services API (see Keychain Services Reference) to put the identities and associated certificates in the keychain."  No! It seems to happen automatically.

2.) I mentioned the fields at the end of the cert in my first post: No Trusted Uses, No Rejected Uses, Alias, and Key ID. I don't believe these are required, but they are set by the openSSL functions
`X509_alias_set1(X509 *x, unsigned char *name, int len)`, and `int X509_keyid_set1(X509 *x, unsigned char *id, int len)`.
The key ID field in the SecPKCS12Import, (`kSecImportItemKeyID`) is determined the by `X509_keyid_set1`. The label field appears to be determined by the common name in the certificate, and not by `X509_alias_set1`. Finally, including trusted or rejected uses is done via the function `sk_ASN1_OBJECT_value`. See x509.h and x509.c for details.  Details on the structure of Key ID can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775340/what-is-an-rsa-key-id). It appears to be the SHA1 hash of the ASN.1 modulus + ASN.1 exponent. I have not thoroughly experimented with this, so your are on your own.

3.) Finally, if the private key is set to NULL in PKCS12_create, the certificate will import into the keychain, though no data structure is returned (assuming it's not already there).

I hope this helps. I found several references to this problem and no clear explanation of what was happening.